# (UWP)System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'

Tags: c#, uwp

This exception occurred at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize) in Measure override method when we use the secondary window.I have used the following code snippet for secondary window in the click event of button

```
        CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
        int newViewId = 0;
        await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Frame frame = new Frame();
            frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondaryPage), null);
            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
            Window.Current.Activate();

            newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        });
        bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
```

Comment: The code snippet you provided works correctly in a blank project. Could you please share a [MCVE] with us?

Comment: Although the error is caught here, it originates within the Navigation Target, so you would need to provide that detail. Issues with `Measure` often present in controls that are programmatically loaded into the UI surface or in 3rd party or custom controls that do not properly support being loaded inside a container where the `Width` or `Height` properties are animated. Focus on the view that you are loading into the frame first, try to navigate to an empty page to prove the concept and isolate the issue.